# Printing the whole line Powershell on word finder

Tags: powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet, select-string

```
$check = $args[1]
$numArgs = $($args.count)
$totMatch = 0
#reset variables for counting

for ( $i = 2; $i -lt $numArgs; $i++ )
{
    $file = $args[$i]
    if ( Test-Path $file ) {
    #echo "The input file was named $file" 
    $match = @(Select-String $check $file -AllMatches | Select -Expand Matches | Select -Expand Value).count
    echo "There were $match Matches in $file"
    echo "There were $match Matches in $file" >> Output.txt

    $totMatch = $totMatch + $match
    }
    else {
        echo "File $file does not exist"
        echo "File $file does not exist" >> Output.txt
    }
}
echo "Total Matches Found: $totMatch"
```

Esentially i created a quick app to find the word searched and check the instances in the file, would anyone know how to edit this to send the whole Line that the word was found in to the Ouput.txt file, So rather on top of instances add the whole line itself? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I can't see that your code works properly; even though you don't say how it's supposed to work (why is `$check` taken from args[1] instead of args[0]?).

Your `Select-String` line is getting the matching lines, then doing some selecting which throws away the line data you want, but doesn't seem to be necessary.

I've reworked it as:

```
$check = $args[0]
$totalMatches = 0

foreach ( $file in $args[1..$args.Length] )
{
    if ( Test-Path $file ) {
        $matches = Select-String $check $file -AllMatches -SimpleMatch

        Write-Output "There were $($matches.Count) Matches in $file" | Tee-Object -FilePath "output.txt" -Append

        foreach ($match in $matches) {
            Write-Output $match.Line | Tee-Object -FilePath "output.txt" -Append
        }

        Write-Host
        $totalMatches = $totalMatches + $matches.Count
    }
    else {
        Write-Output "File $file does not exist" | Tee-Object -FilePath "output.txt" -Append
    }
}

echo "Total Matches Found: $totalMatches"
```

Changes:

- Take the $check as the first argument
- Iterate over the arguments directly instead of counting through them
- Added -SimpleMatch so it doesn't work with regexes, since you didn't mention them
- Removed the `select-object -expand` bits, just grab the select-string results
- Loop through the results and get the line from `$match.line`
- Added `Tee-Object` which both writes to screen and to file in one line

Comment: Thanks! i forgot to add that this code is with a -v option. and neat, i didnt know about the match.line